# How to send email only once in a distributed system

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-transactions

I have a system like this:

- Node reads events off a queue.
- A notification email is sent based on the event, using AWS SES.

The scenarios where issues can arise are:

1. Some other node may also read a duplicate copy of the event in parallel, and thus now 2 emails are sent.
2. Node 1 reads the event, makes the 'send email' call and then dies without acknowledging the sent email. Node 1 doesnt know if the email was sent or not, so it resends after coming back up.

How do i ensure the email is sent only once?

Comment: What type of queue are you using? Most modern queuing systems should help with scenario 1, at least you can setup a at-most-once delivery.  Also, you may have to choose between at-most-once or at-least-once. Which would you choose in that scenario?

Comment: Is this question specially about SQS? Because the answer is going to be different depending on which queue system you use and what that system supports.

Comment: you can assume SQS for this question

Comment: for all queuing, or just the outgoing email queue?

Answer (score 2):

I believe scenario 1 is generally handled by most modern queueing systems. I think there are other questions that address locking issues like that better, so I'll ignore it for the time being.

Regarding scenario 2, most modern queueing systems deal with the same issue - it basically comes down to a question about how you want to fail.

For instance, if you had to choose between delivering the email twice, or not delivering it, which would you choose? In queue parlance, this is described as at-least-once vs. at-most-once delivery.

For these answers, I'm assuming a queueing system like RabbitMQ which enables acks and timeouts.

**Option 1 - Delivering the Email Twice**
Attempt to send the email, and if successful, ack the message to the queue. Setup the queue so that un-acked messages are re-added after a timeout. In this case, if a failure occurs during sending, no ack will occur, and the message will be re-sent to the queue, then picked up again. Now, if there is a consistent failure with the ack (but not your email), you could end up in a situation where you keep sending the email. The majority of the time, however, this shouldn't be a problem.

**Option 2 - Not Delivering The Email**
Setup a queue without ack's. This is generally more performant, so that's a plus. The queue worker will take a message from the queue and attempt the email. If an email fails to send, it won't be retried.

For many of the services I work on (this doesn't apply to email, but does apply to writes to a DB), I try to make them idempotent, then just go with the first option. In the worst case, you churn on writes, but hopefully you have logging to detect this.